# Mist vs dripping irrigation for fruit trees

Tags: fruit-trees, irrigation, drip-system

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?

I suspect that mist is more expensive, but covers a larger area of the tree roots.

[image: mist]
[image: drip]

Comment: you forgot the method of growing in a deep bed of woodchips

Comment: It depends on climate, soil, and your machines. Are you planing an orchard? Could you tell us more about your climate and soil?

Comment: Where have you seen mist on fruit trees? It seems like that would be an invitation for fungi. Also the evaporative loss from misting would be much greater than for drip.

Answer (score 2):

Mist is used in some nurseries and not for fruit trees. Overhead sprinklers or drips are used to trees. Both have pros and cons. Overhead wets leaves and expose them to diseases. It wastes water too. But if you have whiteflies issue, overhead can help reduce their population. Drip saves water but it is more expensive to setup, but running cost is low.